ctx.message.author.activity discord.py
Метод ctx.message.author.activity выводит не полный статус, а только часть. Тоисть, когда ты играешь в какую нибудь игру, и у тебя статус Играет в Сталкер (к примеру), выводит только Сталкер. Можно как нибудь пофиксить?

Вы можете на основе информации с activity.type добавлять в начало строки "Играет в" или "Слушает":
name = ctx.message.author.activity.name
str_activity = {
    discord.ActivityType.playing: f"Играет в {name}",
    discord.ActivityType.listening: f"Слушает {name}",
    }
print(str_activity[ctx.message.author.activity.type])


Спаасибо большое!
